# Erro ao abrir um form dentro de outro form [VB.NET]

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Estou tentando abrir um form dentro de outro form, porém estou com uma certa dificuldade.

A ideia é que quando o clicado no botão "btn_CadastroAlunos" o form  "F_Cadastro_Alunos.vb" seja aberto no panel1 que está presente no form principal "F_Principal.vb"

Meu código está assim no evento Click do botão ("btn_CadastroAlunos"):

```
    Dim NovoForm As New F_Cadastro_Alunos
    NovoForm.TopLevel = False
    NovoForm.Visible = True
    Panel1.Controls.Add(NovoForm)
    NovoForm.Show()
```

Porém ao executar a operação de clicar no botão, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Somente os controles de nível superior podem ter um proprietário.
>   Arg_ParamName_Name'

A imagem a seguir explica um pouco melhor o erro gerado ao tentar exibir o form:

[image: A imagem pode auxiliar no entendimento do meu problema]

Alguém sabe qual a solução?! 
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!

Observação: Estou utilizando o framework: Moden UI

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai conseguir fazer isso com uma form. Acho que seria melhor simplesmente abrir a form e usar `NovoForm.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)`

só substitua os zeros pelo local que você deseja. Ou então, pode usar uma TabControl, e alterar entre os indexes. Isso dá um efeito legal também.